# HTTP Post: File upload occurring prior to HTTP POST

Tags: networking, http, tcp, wireshark

*Note: My apologies if this is the wrong site for this topic. This question was directed to Super User from Network Engineering*

I'm following along the [UMass Wireshark Labs](http://www-net.cs.umass.edu/wireshark-labs/), in particular, [the one on TCP](http://www-net.cs.umass.edu/wireshark-labs/Wireshark_TCP_v7.0.pdf).

In this lab, you're asked to upload a file to a website, and observe the TCP traffic. To my surprise, the transfer of the file being uploaded occurs first (over TCP), BEFORE the `POST` request is made. I cross referenced my capture with the [one they provide (tcp-ethereal-trace-1)](http://gaia.cs.umass.edu/wireshark-labs/wireshark-traces.zip), but it shows the same thing.

This raises a few questions:

- Does the file transfer really occur prior to the HTTP POST request?
- If so, why?
- How does the server know to expect a file?
- How long will it listen and record a file, in anticipation of the POST request?
- Question 7 in the lab asks you to consider the HTTP POST as the first segment in the TCP connection. This seems to contradict the other findings. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the file transfer really occur prior to the HTTP POST request?

No it doesn't. Referring to tcp-ethereal-trace-1 and how it is displayed in wireshark:

- In  frame 1 .. 3 of the dump the TCP handshake is done.
- The POST request starts with frame 4: you see "POST /ethereal-lab .." in the content of the frame.
- The POST request continues until frame 199 which is the last frame of the request.
- This last frame is shown in wireshark as the actual POST because only then are all information collected which are needed to reconstructed the full request. If you look in the details it will also show you that this request was assembled from 122 TCP segments, i.e. all the frames shown which arrived before and where the first frame was the start of the request.

Comment: Oh nice, I missed that content in frame 4. Good stuff!